# I can´t get Javascript code runs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Edit the problem is on the bottom!!

I want to get my autocomplete function to work and always I get this :

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

My script and the html code:

```html
<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title><%--<%= Page.Title %> --%>- Ticketsystem</title>
  <link href="~/Content/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render( "~/bundles/modernizr") %>
  </asp:PlaceHolder>

  <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
  <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />



   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    $(function ()
    {
       $('#tbCompany').autocomplete(
           {
               source: function (request, response)
               {
               $.ajax({
                   url: "Autocomlete.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
                   data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                   success: function (result) {
                       response(result.d);
                   },
                   error: function (result) {
                       alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                   }
               });
           },
           minLength: 0
       });
   });
</script>
```

```html
</asp:PlaceHolder>

  
</head>

<body>
  <form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="tbCompany" runat="server" Style="margin-top:10px" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

I don´t know if my script is wrong or somthing is missing. I tried to put it on the end of my page, in a div or placeholder like suggested from other questions.

edit: Now i did nearly everything what you suggested and now it looks like above and the error below.

error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: Have you tried to change `<%:` to `<%=`?

Comment: Are you using a kind of templates system or jsp to render the html? `<%: Page.Title %>` is not a standar tag of html so you should edit and specify that in the post. I think you need to watch how `#<%=tbCompany.ClientID%>` will be rendered at the final html and replace this selector rendered in that tag

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc or traditional .net? Change `<%: Page.Title %>` to `<%= Page.Title %>`

Comment: its an asp.net web page so the only thing i did was adding my script that means <%: Page.Title %> was already there, i dont quiet get what you mean sry

Comment: i edited my question with the error´s i get

Comment: That all, Is there something more you want to share? Current exception is a run time exception that couldn't handled by the server such error has nothing to do with your Javascript. By judging I could only advice as the rest have said use `<%= ... %>` It's similar to `Response.Write` and place your script either in `head` tag or within `body`.

Comment: Your loading jquery twice and in an wrong sequence. Your jquery UI version use `jquery-1.10.3` but you're loading `jquery-1-9-1` first. Change it and see if it works.

Comment: changed it now i have aother errors

Comment: You have downloaded the jquery ui complete version? Maybe your version haven't the `autocomplete` function.

Comment: i only downloaded the autocomplete with all that got marked when i clicked it

Comment: do i need th jquery-ui.structure.min.css or theme.css?

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Ok, see my answer for a simple cure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112 the inline expression `<%:` doesn't exist.

Try to change `<%: ... %>` to `<%= ... %>`.

Your also loading jquery twice. Your jquery UI version is `1.10.3` but you're loading version `jquery-1.9.1.js`.

Try to load these versions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: changed it didn´t do anything :/

Comment: no sry still same error ith autocomplete is not a funktion

Comment: Sorry, wrong links. I have tested with these and it works.

Comment: put them in and still not working i edited my code above

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your script inside placeholder tag.

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    $(function() {
      $("#<%=tbCompany.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "Autocomlete.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
            data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
              response(result.d);
            },
            error: function(result) {
              alert('There is a problem processing your request');
            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 0
      });
    });
  </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

EDIT: It seems that latest error is because of missing jQuery UI js or incorrect sequence. Can you remove all the jQuery related js files and add the latest version of jQuery afterthat jQuery UI in your code ?

Comment: well i do not get any error at least but it isn´t working. can you tell me if it is correct as far as you can tell ?

Comment: did you try placing a breakpoint in the GetCompanyNames ? Does it hit ? Also, find out if if the control goes to success function or error function using debugger

Comment: it seems that latest error is because of missing jQuery UI js or incorrect sequence. Can you remove all the jQuery related js files and add the latest version of jQuery afterthat jQuery UI in your code ?

Comment: thanks but already did that and you are right there was a scriptreference i didnt saw

Answer (score 0):

it seems too many jQuery files added in the head, try to use only one jquery and it may resolve this issue

you can just use only the latest version minified file.

Comment: changed it didn´t do anything :/  now i only have 10.2.min.js, 10.2.js and 10.2.intellisense.js

Comment: use only 10.2.min.js remove 10.2.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading Jquery-ui.{version}.js as i can't see it in your code that is for autocomplete error.

If you are writing code in seprate js file then <% %> will not work , In Place of that you can use ClientIDMode as static and in place aspx syntax you can use

```
$("#tbCompany")
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%# tbCompany.ClientID %>` instead `<%=tbCompany.ClientID%>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    $(function() {
      $("#<%# tbCompany.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "Autocomlete.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
            data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
              response(result.d);
            },
            error: function(result) {
              alert('There is a problem processing your request');
            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 0
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mind try separated the 
"#<%=tbCompany.ClientID%>" 
use variable? As:
<%= String value = tbCompany.ClientID%>
And :$("#value")....
May the "autocomplete" is not the point.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, you're using .net 4.5.

.net 4 bought with it some changes to the asp.net controls. Especially one attribute called `ClientIDMode`

This allows you to control how ASP.Net renders and renames the ID of controls. You can now tell .net to leave them alone..

You can change this:

`$('#<%=tbCompany.ClientID%>').autocomplete({...`

To this:

`$('#tbCompany').autocomplete({...`

And on the element with the ID of `tbCompany` add the attribute `ClientIDMode="static"` - this will tell .net to leave the ID alone and use whatever you have set.

See more about [ClientIDMode here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: If that's the case, then you have other <%%> in the page. If you have changed the $('#tbCompany') and added the ClientIDMode to the correct element then you 100% have other inline code

Comment: Edited the code above there isnt another inline code i checked